# Issues with Data Sorting

Tags: powerbi

I have issues with Data sorting

I have spend data by period which is a combination of year and month. For example if the period is March 2019 then period would show 201903. Data type of this period field is "Number". I have spend data starting from period 201501 to 201903.

Now I am creating a line chart to show spend trend with period in X axis and spend in Y axis. I have sorted (ascending) the chart by period, however sorting works ok partially, means period that I see in the chart are mentioned below:-

201708,201801,201806,201807,201808,201809,201810,201811,201812,201901,201902,201903

Not sure why sorting option is not working

Also in the Visual Level filter I want to show trailing 12 months spend, details of Visual Level filters that i selected are as follows:-

Visual Level Filter - Period
Filter Type - Top N
Show item - Bottom 12
By Value - Spend Amount

The expected result that I want in the line chart is :-

201804,201805,201806,201807,201808,201809,201810,201811,201812,201901,201902,201903

I checked the data and confirm it has all periods starting from 201501 to 201903

Any help would be highly appreciated[image]

Comment: Looks like you have filtered values (spend) with 0 values. Remove that filter and you will get what you are looking for. Also, make sure the X-Axis property "Type" is not set to chronological

Comment: @PratikBhavsar There is no filter on value filed, also X axis is categorical

Comment: Try each of the x axis types. I am not sure which one is preferable in this scenario.

Comment: Seems logic to me as you are not using real date colums but numbers instead. I propose you convert your column to date.